# module declares its path as: but was required as:

Tags: golang

форкнул библиотеку, переименовал, поменял имя в го.мод
при установке выдаёт ошибку, решения с англоязычного so попробовал, но не помогло, не могу разобраться в чём дело

```
go get github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4
go: github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4@upgrade (v4.0.1) requires github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4@v4.0.1: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: github.com/aaaton/golem/v4
                but was required as: github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4
```

Comment: pinus это сосна на латыни, библиотека нужна для сервиса связанного с деревьями*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При наличии релизов `go get` скачивает не исходный код из дефолтной ветки, а помеченные релизы. В вашем случае скачивается архив из https://github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/releases/tag/v4.0.1 Этот релиз был сделан в 2020-м году, и в его `go.mod` модуль именован как `github.com/aaaton/golem/v4`

Есть два пути.

Первый: [сделать новый релиз](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository#creating-a-release) из обновлённых файлов. Например, 4.0.2. Команда `go get github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4@latest` автоматически найдёт новый релиз и установит его.

Второй: установить конкретный коммит. Сейчас у вас самый свежий коммит `46580a27022e1c0ef052ed37380c3ebb55c28668`. Его можно добавить командой

```
$ go get github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4@46580a27022e1c0ef052ed37380c3ebb55c28668
```

Результат:

```
go: downloading github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4 v4.0.2-0.20240113124823-46580a27022e
go: added github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4 v4.0.2-0.20240113124823-46580a27022e
```

Comment: я сделал как вы сказали, но вот есть момент, который видимо не сработал. У библиотеки есть зависимость (прописана в мейкфайле на 37 строке), с ней можно грамотно организовать как-то?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Вам нужно форкнуть проект https://github.com/michmech/lemmatization-lists/ и скачивать файлы из своего форка.

Comment: спасибо получилось, есть какие-то способы понять что именно мой форкнутый леммматизейшн лист качается? Я в свой лист добавил слово геймдизайн(его не было), однако оно не лемматизируется

Comment: @SpaceResearcher разделитель между колонками в файле lemmatization-lists должен быть табуляцией. Проверьте, что у вас не пробелы. И ещё, я попробовал собрать ваш проект - вам нужно поправить  шаблон в `cmd/genpack/genpack.go`: там делается импорт `aaaton/golem`, а вам нужно импортировать `golem "github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/v4"`

Comment: Николай, спасибо большое!

Comment: Спустя несколько попыток вынужден опять отнимать ваше время с вопросами. Как понять когда именно работает genpack.go, у меня сложилось ощущение что он не вызывается при скачивании библиотки.  В моём форке и в оригинальной версии получаются в исходниках одинаковые значения переменной data файла pack.go , которая как раз содержит в себе запакованный и закодированный словарик. Выходит, что оба репозитория форкнуты , оба связаны как надо, но судя по всему сборка не происходит, это надо как-то дополнительно настраивать?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher `genpack.go` вызывается в Makefile, правило `make package`. Насколько я понимаю, идея в том, чтобы собрать заранее все необходимые языки и запушить в гитхаб. Клиенты скачивают уже готовые лексические пакеты.

Comment: то есть клиенты скачивать уже готовый pack.go с уже готовым словарём? А я его должен просто заранее собрать и выложить релиз с готовым, верно?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher на самом деле скачивают как пакет `golempinus/v4`, так и пакет `golempinus/v4/dicts/ru`. Так написано в [примере](https://github.com/Ernesto-Che-Guevara/golempinus/blob/master/README.md). Вообще, это плохой дизайн, я бы разделил генератор, морфологию и инфраструктуру, но пока так.